# How to encrypt the content assets folder in phonegap android application

Tags: android, cordova, reverse-engineering

I have developed a sample android application using phonegap,If someone reverse engineers the apk file,They can easily get the javascript,html files .
What is the best way to secure javascript and html files in the assets folder since i will be defining lot of api keys in the javascript source files which should be hidden.